# How to hacks pretty URL link rel in WP

Tags: wordpress, url, url-routing

Generally, when I open the source page, basic thing when I see on my CSS or JS link rel is like below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="http://blog.zakariyasoewardi.co.uk/wp-content/themes/wordpress-bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less">
```

I use third party plugin who claim can make nobody know I use WP, I'm sure my link rel will be like below if I setting with that:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="http://blog.zakariyasoewardi.co.uk/node/1/wordpress-bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less">
```

But in specific case, I need hack URL link rel much easier when people or I shot the source page, this is what I mean:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="/wordpress-bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less">
```

Is it possible?
I believe several developer can, I notice few of Website where I included in their service as member does well.

Comment: So why do you need to obscure the face that you're using wordpress? If you don't want people to know for some reason, then perhaps you shouldn't use wordpress in my opinion. I dont believe this belongs in the optimization tag either.

Comment: Perfect, you answered your question, because "some reason". I'm here to solving my problem and share my experience, not for commenting.

Comment: This attitude (zake) will not get you any help.  If you don't want comments, don't ask questions here.

Comment: Let me straight, I don't know what I'm saying wrong or not @cale_b. If I offend, I will say sorry. But, in specific case, it's clear I had a problem in Wordpress, and people say why I use Wordpress, come on.

Comment: Zake, SMT did not say "why are you using WordPress".  SMT said "why are you **hiding** the fact that you are using WordPress".  That's very different.  If you are going to use WordPress (which is great), then why are you trying to hide that fact?  (BTW, it's virtually impossible to successfully hide that fact, so you might as well NOT bother).

Comment: Ok, in short I don't want argue, that's ok with what he said and I'll stand. It's not about hiding fact, mostly advance users can using Wpscan to knowing. But I need securely and have some reason to do that, as simple as I can to clear header and "hacks" the url.

Comment: Good attitude @zake that will get you far...

Answer (score 0):

There are already answers for what you want to do:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hide+wordpress

and

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=hide+wordpress

and on the web in general

http://www.google.com/search?q=hide+wordpress

That said, this is called *security through obscurity*, which really isn't security at all. Bots will still find the fact that you are using WordPress. Casual viewers of browser source will, too. You're basically wasting your time.

You're much better off leaving all that alone and reading http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress and being sure you're on a good, secure web host.

WordPress isn't necessarily or chronically insecure (though, like any software package, vulnerabilities keep popping up). The main issue is that WordPress is very popular - 50 million sites and counting, they say, at the time of this post - and that makes it a target in terms of lots of insecure themes, plugins and sketchy hosts that cater to the WordPress ecosystem. And that means lots of targets in terms of millions of sites that may be mis-configured in terms of security.